# How to handle deep links with Navigation 1.0 in a Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation, flutter-deep-link

I am currently using Navigation 1.0 and want to add deep links within the current navigation setup. I am aware that it is simple to add deep links with Navigation 2.0 using packages like go_router. However, I want to implement deep links without relying on any additional packages such as go_router, uni_links, or Firebase.

I have read a couple of articles where they explain the process using the mentioned packages, I prefer not to use them. i'm expecting to handle deep-links the current navigation 1.0 setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it's possible without writing a native code. Here is an example:

**First** configure the project for deep linking. Add schemas in the manifest file

```
// AndroidManifest.xml

<intent-filter android:autoVerify="false">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="test.com" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
    <data
        android:host="test.com"
        android:scheme="myapp" />
</intent-filter>
```

**Then** add onGenerateRoute parameter to the MaterialApp widget

```
// main.dart

onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
  switch (settings.name) {
    case '/':
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => HomePage());
    case '/login':
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LoginPage());
    case '/deep':
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => DeepPage());
    default:
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => HomePage());
  }
},
```

**Now**, by opening this link the app is opened with the route `/deep` (DeepPage):
myapp://test.com/deep

**Note:** This example contains configuration for basic testing of a deep link. For the correct configuration for your project, and using universal app links on both android and iOS, follow instructions on [this page](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/set-up-app-links) (except the GoRouter part).

And [here](https://github.com/mahdinba97/flutter-deep-linking-demo) is the example project

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to handle deep-links without using any package. You need to write some native code to handle it though, That's exactly why we use packages like uni_links or app_links.

Although, this link is mentioned in [official flutter docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/navigation/deep-linking#migrating-from-plugin-based-deep-linking) for deep-linking using native code (by writing a native plugin): [Deep Links and Flutter applications. How to handle them properly](https://medium.com/flutter-community/deep-links-and-flutter-applications-how-to-handle-them-properly-8c9865af9283)

Comment: The link mentioned [official flutter doc - Deep linking](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/navigation/deep-linking) states that Flutter supports deep linking using named routes, either with the routes parameter or onGenerateRoute. Are there any examples of how to achieve this?

Comment: I think you are right. It seems that if you add the pages like mentioned [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/navigation#using-named-routes), and add the schemes to the manifest file and info.plist file, you can access the page by opening the link like this (www.scheme/my-route). But it has some limitations as mentioned on the same page. Although, I will give it a try to see if it's this easy and possible, and send an example in a separate answer here.